# maven is "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" - letsencrypt ssl certificate

Tags: apache, maven, ssl, lets-encrypt

I recently switched to [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates for my maven repo (Artifactory behind Apache proxy). Repo access via browser works fine, showing no problems with the certificate (screenshot below).

It also works if I [import the certificate manually into the java keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail/11617655#11617655).

But according to this SO question, [Java should accept letsencrypt certificates starting with 8u101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110426/does-java-support-lets-encrypt-certificates).

I am always getting this exception:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

[image]

[image]

```
C:\myproject>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\jdk1.8_win64\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out, 3 months later...

The apache server in front of the maven artifactory repository was not configured to provide the intermediate certificate in the chain.

I downloaded the intermediate certificate - [Let’s Encrypt Authority X3 (IdenTrust cross-signed)](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) - and configured apache to serve it, too.

Actually, the `domain.crt` file contains both the domain and the intermediate certificate, and for all of my test browsers that was always good enough. But the eclipse/maven setup on that one machine could not handle it.

I only started to look into the apache config after an [SSL Labs check](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)  told me that the certificate chain was incomplete (even though no browser seemed to care).

Before:

```
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "path/to/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "path/to/domain.key"
```

After:

```
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "path/to/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "path/to/domain.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "path/to/letsencrypt-authority-x3-identrust.pem"
```

Comment: This answer was a huge help -- thanks! Note that the letsencrypt bot should download this file for you by default, and store it at `/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/chain.pem`.  Updating my config with this file, as per your answer, solved the issue for me.