# How SSL Handshaking works in Java 7 vs Java 8

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

Recently while working with HttpClient for accessing 3rd party service (CURL Service) in Java application, I came across problem like:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
....
```

I got this problem in JDK 7. With some research on this problem I found 2 suggestions i.e.

- Add certificate of that particular 3rd party in your JDK 7 Truststore. [Which I tried but still got same issue]
- Use JDK 8 instead of JDK 7 [Which I tried and it worked for me]

So I am trying to understand like **how SSL Handshaking takes place in Java 8 as compare to Java 7 or lower? And I can fix this issue in JDK7**

**Code Snnipet**

```
public String getProduct(final String accessToken) throws IOException, ParseException {

    log.info("accessToken: " + accessToken);
    final String stringUrl = "https://api.molt.in/v1/products";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(stringUrl);
    getRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest, httpContext);
    log.info("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    log.info("result: " + result);

    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

~Regards,

Chandan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server closes the handshake because the client uses an unsupported protocol. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21245796/315306), where it's suggested to launch Java 7 with:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

You'd get an error from your client (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed) if the server certificate were not trusted, and it works this way: the Java client checks the server's certificate to be sure that the machine it is talking to is actually who it claims to be, in your example "api.molt.in". The check works like this:

- if the certificate is self signed, it is trusted if found in the default trust store
- if the certificate is signed by an authority, it is trusted if the authority's certificate is found in the default trust store.

The list of trusted parties may be updated in every Java minor release. For example certificates generated with [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) are only trusted by Java 8 [since the 101 update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111150/315306).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It worked. Earlier also I tried to update the Https Protocol version but because of some other exception I removed it Again after adding this, it worked for me... Thank you

Comment: You can "accept" this answer as the correct one by toggling the "v" mark on the left of the text