# Java - Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to get an HTML source code of a site.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://www.trackobot.com/");
        is = url.openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But, when run this code, I get an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
   at JsoupTutorial.ConnectToUrl.main(ConnectToUrl.java:24)
```

If I change the site, it work well, even with https sites like PayPal. But, still I have some sites that it just don't work and throw that exception. This site in the example is one of those sites that it don't work.

I searched for it and understand that I need to import the certificate of this site to the Java keystore. **Am I correct?**

My question is how Chrome do manage to enter those "Secure" sites ang get the HTML code? someone has to update (import) the certificate to the Chrome Cer database..who do this and when it happen? (Just in case that i'm correct above).

Anyway, I'm want to manage to load those sites perfect and receive the data I want. Where can I learn it from the basic?

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at this for a full explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111150 and this for Let's Encrypt certificate compatibility list https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is almost certainly that you're trying to access a site which uses SSL/HTTPS, but you aren't using an API which supports that.  You may try using `HttpsURLConnection` with a (bad) trust store which accepts everything.  *Don't ever do this in production*.

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

URL url = new URL("https://www.trackobot.com/");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        return true;
    }
});
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
}
in.close();

System.out.println(response.toString());

private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ideally `HttpsURLConnection` out of the box should work fine assuming that the domain presents a certificate from a relatively standard provider.  Since it doesn't work for your domain, we can configure it to trust everything.  Bad in production, but maybe lets you proceed for the time being.

Comment: trackobot.com still not working. But the other site that didn't work before seem to work well now. It seem that trackobot has no standard provide for cert and the other site do have. But, how  trackobot work on Chrome. Can you explain? please. Thank you very much.

Comment: @oriel Try my updated code, which may require you to tweak it a bit to get it to run and compile.

Comment: Yes, it work! I need to read and understand what you did there. Thank you very much!!

Comment: BAD solution, that should be used for DEBUG purposes only! This would be fine if used PER connection (not globally), just like the HostnameVerifier bypass was done.