# most mandatory plugins in Jenkins are not getting installed

Tags: jenkins

i am trying to use Jenkins in my local system, i do get Java Certificate as below, i do use jdk11 version in my system, in case you know how to add certificate or resolution link for the below problem, kindly share it to me

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1313)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1151)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2758)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2680)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1843)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1296)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/script-security/1183.v774b_0b_0a_a_451/script-security.hpi to C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\plugins\script-security.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1307)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/script-security/1183.v774b_0b_0a_a_451/script-security.hpi (redirected to: https://get.jenkins.io/plugins/script-security/1183.v774b_0b_0a_a_451/script-security.hpi)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1341)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1898)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2210)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1872)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Execut`enter code enter code herehere`ors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as "mandatory Jenkins plugins". Try [some basic searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jenkins%22+plugins+%22PKIX+path+building+failed%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) before poating

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" error while importing Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563694/jenkins-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-whil)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled Java 11, Jenkins in my Windows 10 System, Installed Java 17 with Jenkins LTS - Plugins. then tried to login Jenkins, the Plugins got automatically downloaded.